# ClickOnce published an application installed from web showing annoying "Launching Application" window every time I run it

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, clickonce

I just published a C# [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application with the "From a Web Site" option. Then I installed it in my computer and successfully ran it. The only problem is that every time I run my installed application, this window pops up and then disappears:

[image: ClickOnce application display "Verifying application requirements. This may take a few moments." at startup]

Is there any way to get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Project -> Properties -> Publish -> Updates and either uncheck "The application should check for updates" or select "After the application starts". The message box is only shown when the application is checking for updates before the application starts.

Answer (score 0):

When you are publishing on the localhost or on web, please check the setting of the update condition in Project > Properties > Publish > Prerequisites and uncheck it as required. This will prevent it from checking for the appropriate version of the .NET Framework, among other things.

Hope this will help.

Comment: But I do want it to check for prerequisites but just at install time. Is this possible?

Comment: If then, try using a install instead of clickonce :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project>Properties>Publish>Prerequisites and uncheck "The application should check for updates".

If you want to still check for updates, then you can do so programmatically.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404263.aspx